# UTM Campaign Tracking to Goals / Conversions

Tags: google-analytics

I have UTM tracking setup and can see that sessions are being attributed against each Campaign, Source, Medium etc..  What it doesn't do is attribute any Goals / conversions to the campaigns.  Anyone got any ideas?
Thanks!
S

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: http://www.evoka.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/analyticsscreenshot.png

Comment: Hi Dieter, see screenshot on the above url.  as you can see there are no conversions attributed to the campaigns.  I know for a fact that some traffic from those campaigns has triggered a conversion (i can see from the completion url)

Comment: the goal is triggered through Google Tag Manager event (some one hitting a URL containing "/?sucessfullcompletion"  http://www.evoka.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/goal.png

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two options:

1. Make one segment that contains ALL USERS THAT CLICKED on your campaing and then go and see the results in the Goal section.
2. The "All capaigns report" from the LeftPanel->Conversions. Here you will need to filter/choose the campaign and you will see all your goals, and for more details you can specify the specific goal you want to see.